# Attempted import error: 'styles' is not exported from './styles'

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to import styles from `style.js` file and the that file contains below code

```
    const export styles = {
    border: 'solid',
    textAlign : 'center',
    boxShadow : '2px 2px'
  }
```

But it shows the below error in that file

```
'export' is not allowed as a variable declaration name.
```

But when I add the `export` keyword as shown below code

```
    const styles = {
    border: 'solid',
    textAlign : 'center',
    boxShadow : '2px 2px'
  }
    export default styles;
```

And trying to import in my component as

```
import * as styles from "./styles";

<div style={styles.styles}>
          Style
</div>
```

I am getting the below error

```
Attempted import error: 'styles' is not exported from './styles'.
```

How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Use this way `style.js`

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({

});
```

And trying to import in my component as

```
import styles from "./styles";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try export as default

```
 const styles = {
    border: 'solid',
    textAlign : 'center',
    boxShadow : '2px 2px'
  }
  export default styles;
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code it worked for me

```
 export const externalStyles = {
    color : 'red',
    backgroundColor: 'green'
}
```